# "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory" on Ember CLI Mirage

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-cli-mirage

I'm an extreme beginner. I'm trying to use Mirage based on the guides shown on the ember website. All my code is more or less the same as in their guide. However, when I go to localhost, I get a Build Error and the following:

```
    dateisrael/mirage/config.js (in /Users/aarontaylor/dateisrael/tmp/babel-input_base_path-B9ZXdbHw.tmp/0)

The Broccoli Plugin: [Babel] failed with:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/aarontaylor/dateisrael/tmp/babel-output_path-qYd6ESrZ.tmp/dateisrael/mirage/config.js'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:549:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:397:15)
    at Babel.asyncOutputFilteredFile (/Users/aarontaylor/dateisrael/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/broccoli-persistent-filter/index.js:216:23)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$tryCatch (/Users/aarontaylor/dateisrael/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/broccoli-persistent-filter/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1036:16)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$invokeCallback (/Users/aarontaylor/dateisrael/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/broccoli-persistent-filter/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1048:17)
    at lib$rsvp$$internal$$publish (/Users/aarontaylor/dateisrael/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/broccoli-persistent-filter/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1019:11)
    at lib$rsvp$asap$$flush (/Users/aarontaylor/dateisrael/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/broccoli-persistent-filter/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:1198:9)
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)

The broccoli plugin was instantiated at: 
    at Babel.Plugin (/Users/aarontaylor/dateisrael/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/broccoli-persistent-filter/node_modules/broccoli-plugin/index.js:7:31)
    at Babel.Filter [as constructor] (/Users/aarontaylor/dateisrael/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/broccoli-persistent-filter/index.js:38:10)
    at new Babel (/Users/aarontaylor/dateisrael/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/index.js:34:10)
    at Babel (/Users/aarontaylor/dateisrael/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/node_modules/broccoli-babel-transpiler/index.js:29:12)
    at Object.registry.add.toTree (/Users/aarontaylor/dateisrael/node_modules/ember-cli-babel/index.js:21:52)
    at /Users/aarontaylor/dateisrael/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/ember-cli-preprocess-registry/preprocessors.js:184:26
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at processPlugins (/Users/aarontaylor/dateisrael/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/ember-cli-preprocess-registry/preprocessors.js:182:11)
    at module.exports.preprocessJs (/Users/aarontaylor/dateisrael/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/ember-cli-preprocess-registry/preprocessors.js:175:10)
    at EmberApp.appAndDependencies (/Users/aarontaylor/dateisrael/node_modules/ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js:1044:25)
```

I tried `ember generate ember-cli-mirage` again after it didn't work but this didn't help.

What can I do to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: what version of mirage? (Look in your package.json file)

Comment: "ember-cli-mirage": "0.1.13"

Comment: Did you restart the server?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but is that the same thing as just turning it off and on again? If so, yes, I tried that.

Comment: Actually, I'm not getting the build error anymore (although I am getting another one), so restarting might have worked!